# Why doesn't my Table get created?

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb, table

I am working on creating a table in the DB for a plugin but cannot figure out why the table is not being created.

Here's my code:

```
global $ds_swoons_db_version;
$ds_swoons_db_version = '1.0';

function ds_swoons_install(){
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "ds_entry_swoons";    

if( $wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$table_name'") != $table_name ):
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $table_name . " (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            post_id int(9) NOT NULL,
            user_id (9) NOT NULL,
            swoon_status int(1),
            UNIQUE KEY id (id)
            );";
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    //make the query
    dbDelta($sql);
    //add db verison number
    add_option('ds_swoons_db_version', $ds_swoons_db_version);
endif;

}//end ds_swoons_install

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ds_swoons_install');
```

I tried to echo the error but get an unexpected output error - probably due to headers being sent already. This is all the code I have so far - just wanted to see if I could create the table before moving on to anything else.

Thanx in advance!

EDIT ----------------------------------------------------

I figured it out - I did not have the data type declaration for user_id so it never created the table. I changed it and it worked :)

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer rather than in your question. It just helps the community read easier.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the heads up. I answered the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - I did not have the data type declaration for user_id so it never created the table. I changed it and it worked :)